# VBA- add data to next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the below macro to transfer data from one worksheet to another. I want the new data being transferred to an empty row, but it keeps overwriting the same to rows

```
  Worksheets("sheet1").Select
     Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Select
     RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
     .Offset(RowCount, 0) = workOrderDescription
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below:

```
With Workbooks("Your_WorkbookmName").Worksheets("sheet1")
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- get last row in column "A"
    .Range("A" & RowCount + 1) = workOrderDescription
End With
```

Comment: Hi my explanation wasn't very clear. I'm transferring from one worksheet to a different workbook. I want the data to transfer to an empty rown on each occassion

Comment: @Tom indeed your explanation is not very clear, what is the name of the other workbook ? is it open ? what is the sheet's name you want to copy to ?

Comment: At the moment I haven't named the workbook or sheet. It's just sheet 1 at the moment while I test the macros. It'll be open through out the day when it's actually working, and constantly receiving updates from the workbook sending the data through.

Comment: @Tom try edited code, change "Your_WorkbookmName" to your workbook's name

Comment: very nice but how would you do this with a nested loop? ie without a counter? `do for each item *your code here* Next item  *your code here* loop  until..`

Comment: @Shia I guess what I'm asking is do you create another Workbooks object to the same "sheet1" to continue adding data from the last line? Because it did not work when I tried. Either it adds the data from the inside loop or the outside loop, not both. Any idea?